# Building libhexagon nnlib issue : (No rule to make target `adspmsgd.a')

Tags: tensorflow, sdk, qualcomm, hexagon-dsp

I am using SDK 3.0, nnlib version(721b2d58f) as suggested in [TF-HVX](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/hvx/) and passed the compilation tree of `make tree VERBOSE=1 V=hexagon_Release_dynamic_toolv72_v60`, however, on the android compilation (`make tree VERBOSE=1 V=android_Release`), I am stuck with this error:

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `adspmsgd.a', needed by `android_Release/graph_app'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `~/Hexagon_SDK/3.0/examples/common/nnlib'
```

Could anyone successfully pass this error?